# What does gRPC, over HTTP/2 means?

Tags: http, google-cloud-platform, grpc

What does operations are done with gRPC, over HTTP/2 means. I am interested in knowing how does gRPC and HTTP/2 play along.

Comment: https://grpc.io/

Answer (score 3):

gRPC is a protocol that uses HTTP/2.  The messages you send are encoded as gRPC frames (5 byte header) and packaged into HTTP/2 DATA frames.   The HTTP/2 HEADERS frames are used to propagate headers and trailers at the beginning and end of the call.

It would be possible to use gRPC over other protocols, though this is less common as of this writing.   For example:

- gRPC can be used In Process, meaning there is no wire encoding.  You still get to use the same gRPC API and Stubs though.  This is commonly used for testing
- QUIC:   This is a UDP based protocol that is an alternative to HTTP/2, but which has HTTP semantics.   This is used on Android Java when using the AndroidChannelBuilder.
- HTTP/1.1:  This is used for gRPC Web.  Some minor modifications are needed to the gRPC protocol, but it can work from regular web browsers which currently don't support certain parts of HTTP/2.